# To delete multiple rows by Excel VBA command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet with command button to select and delete one row.
Deletion can be done only for Rows after 12th row. below is the code I have:-

```
Sub Button_delete_row()
If ActiveCell.Row > 12 Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxxx"
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
ActiveSheet.Protect "xxxx", True, True
End If
End Sub
```

With my above code in command button, I can select only one row by highlighting with mouse click and deleting.
My problem is I want to select multiple rows by highlighting with mouse drag and click on command button to delete these rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use the following?

```
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

You can select multiple cells, click the button, and the associated row will be deleted.